# ¿ Ctrl + c Habra otra forma de salir en un script bash?

Tags: bash, script

**Como podría ponerla una forma de salida al script , para poder salir tengo que presionar la letra : `crtl + c` para poder salir. Habra otra forma de salida del script**

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
clear
echo      -------Script Traductor  ----------
echo -ne "Porfavor ingrese un texto: ";read txt
echo
echo -e "---El resultado es:" $(trans -b es:en "$txt")
#este escript  sirve  para traducir idioma y quiero poner una salida del script  , para yo poder salir del script tengo que escribir la letra: ctrl+ c
echo
done
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que haz intentado para añadir una extensión?

Comment: El script  es para traducir idioma , para poder salir  del scritp tengo que presionar la letra :```ctrl +c ```  habrá otra manera de hacerlo

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que haz investigado acerca de la forma de salir de un script? Para que se te pueda ayudar sobre dudas concretas. No sólo el código que llevas, sino lo que haz intentado para resolver tu propia duda.

Answer (score 0):

Algo muy simple y que utilizo en los script en bash es al final incluir un

```
exit
```

Por ejemplo.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba a añadir una comprobación en la siguiente línea al read:

```
if [[ "${txt}" = "q" ]]; then exit 0; fi;
```

Si en el texto introduces el caracter 'q' saldrás del script.

Comment: Como en donde la siguiente  línea de ```read txt```?

Comment: @Kenia Si, se refiere a que si al hacer el read en texto se almacena solo la letra q, que la ejecución termine.